# I cannot flag duplicate

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

Some time ago, [some question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823421/sicstus-prolog-upgrade-in-x86-platform) was asked, which I answered.

Now, the [very same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194663/upgrade-to-4-2-3-sicstus-prolog-and-64-bit-addressing) is asked again. This time,  by another user [ayyappa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1624157/ayyappa), which looks quite similar to the original asker.

As I flagged the question as duplicate, my flagging was denied, because the original question did not have an answered or upvoted answer.

What to do?

Comment: I've upvoted your answer and voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: Wait for the new question to get some answers and then flag the other one as a duplicate.

Comment: @JonW Even if an answer was added to the new question, it would still have to be upvoted before flagging/closing is possible.

Comment: I also flagged, asking to check possible sock puppet. They do look like the same person.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes that looks two account of same person. However `Ayyappa` is common name in my country's south side.

Answer (score 3):

If one of the answers under one of the questions is good, upvote it (or, if it's yours, wait for it to get upvoted). Then vote to close as duplicates.

If you suspect sock puppetry, flag for diamond moderator's attention and describe the issue.

If there is no sock puppetry happening, and neither question got an answer, leave them be. The one that will attract answer sooner is probably better worded and the other should be closed, but if both was honest attempts to ask good question, closing either of them too soon wouldn't be good.